# multi-language wordpress site

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess, internationalization

My goal is to be able to access an URL like `blog.xxx.com/my-post-name-permalink`
and getting redirected to either `blog.xxx.com/en/my-post-name-permalink` or `blog.xxx.com/de/my-post-name-permalink` depending on the geo location from the ip addr.

I am not familiar with `WP_MULTISITE`, I can't seem to get it working but I didn't try much anyways. Maybe I can use seperate installations aswell. The downsite of having to upgrade each installation seperately is not too bad for me, the important thing for me is having the same post in different languages (which I'd translate myself).

I think the best way is to just code a location switch in `blog.xxx.com/index.php` that redirects accordingly in combination with `.htaccess` ModRewrite.

Is there a better / simpler way?

Answer (score 4):

You can use this plugin for multilingual support in wordpress:

[Qtranslate](http://wordpress.org/plugins/qtranslate/)

Using this plugin you can achieve this task.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Adds userfriendly multilingual content management and translation support into WordPress. 
qTranslate supports infinite languages, which can be easily added/modified/deleted via the comfortable Configuration Page. All you need to do is activate the plugin and start writing the content!
[Qtransalate wordpress plugin](http://wordpress.org/plugins/qtranslate/screenshots/)

Answer (score 0):

DONT use qtranslate, it's not updated/patch properly... please use ONLY mQtranslate, a fork of the plugin that is keep up-to-date, and the code is compatible up to 4. I have more than 15 site running qtranslate, all of them migrated to mQtranslate because of the poor support of the original...You have been warned

https://wordpress.org/plugins/mqtranslate/